# Windows Script Host cannot find the file on startup

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file, wsh

I am having here a vbs-file which starts a batch script. The batch should run invisible, so i use this vbs-script:

```
WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ).Run "loop.bat",0,0
```

The vbs is registered to the run-key in the registry-

Everytime on startup it tells me that he cannot find the specified file.
Maybe the Windows Script Host is starting to late for my vbs-script?

What should I do?

vbs with delayed start? This needs another loop, but my script shall be invisible.

vbs in the startupfolder? Better taking the registry. For other reasons I cannot use the startupfolder.

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Does the problem happen also when you specify the full path name of loop.bat (such as `WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ).Run "C:\Scripts\loop.bat",0,0`)?

Comment: I was blind, but now I can see ;)  WSH is not a service that has to be started first. VBS and Bat are in the same folder but unusually still I have to give the whole path. It works now fine, thank you fmunkert ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old... But i thought I'd put this in in case anyone stumbles here.

if you add something to run, when it starts unless otherwise specified it's working directory is C:\Windows\System32 so if you point to a file, "mybat.bat" it will assume it's in c:\windows\system32\mybat.bat

that's why you need to specify the whole path in the vbs.

if you are in a bat file then add this to the top of your file:

```
PUSHD %~dp0
```

Martyn

Comment: You can also add the file to System > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables as "mybat.bat" so that when it's called in the startup vbs as simply mybat.bat Windows knows where to find it if it isn't in system32.